# Fontspec finding no fonts for XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
  \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
  \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}

\begin{document}
X marks the spot.
\end{document}
```

Using the standard ISO of TeXLive 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04.1, LuaLaTex compiles this; XeLaTeX, on the other hand, gives this error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Latin Modern Roman" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.4   \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

What’s going on, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

is sufficient. It will set the fonts to Latin Modern by default. That said, your code compiles fine for me.

I am not that familiar with XeLaTeX. However, I know it uses OS fonts and I know it handles things differently from LuaLaTeX. So you may need to tell your system about the TeX fonts. For example, I have the following configuration file `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/09-texlive-fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

This is then sym linked from `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`. You then would need to update the `fontconfig` cache etc. However, the best way to handle this is to see if your distro has a package which does something similar when its own packages are installed. If it does, just follow the lead of that package, adapting it for an upstream install.

Useful commands: `mkfontscale`, `mkfontdir` `fc-cache`. But check your distro - it may prefer wrappers for some of these commands.

Note that my use of `current` may not work for you. You likely need `2014` instead.

Comment: Fortunately, this works in this particular case, but I would like to keep waiting for further answers, since my original code **used** to work.

Comment: @AdamKhan And it ***should*** work. It works for me. Are you sure that the Latin Modern fonts are installed system-wide? (Not just for TeX.) Can you use other system fonts?

Comment: @AdamKhan Just realised: don't mark this answer as accepted! You are hoping for a more satisfactory one. If you don't get one in a couple of days, it would be reasonable to accept this one. But don't do it now. (You can unaccept it, I think.)

Comment: System fonts work, even those with spaces. Only TeX fonts fail. I used `sudo ./install-tl` to install TeXLive.

Comment: @AdamKhan I do not use XeLaTeX much but, as I understand it, it uses system fonts. So I think you need to have the TeX fonts included with your system fonts. (LuaLaTeX does things a bit differently.) For example, I created...

Comment: Just an FYI. Symlinking to this file from /etc/fonts/conf.d/ messed up my system fonts. Firefox went bonkers. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @jdw This is how distros do it when they integrate the fonts into the system. TeX Live also has a copy of this file or similar somewhere, I think. 'Firefox went bonkers' isn't an error. If you can provide more information, by all means ask a new question or comment again, but otherwise this is just a WFM.